# Jupyter: Recover cell information after deleting the info and the cell

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

What I do in a Jupyter Notebook:

1. Write something in a cell and run it.
2. Select all and delete the content.
3. Delete the cell
4. Edit -> Undo Delete Cells
5. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>

But the information won't come back. Can I recover that information or shall I consider it completely lost forever?

Comment: I've been using Jupyter daily for nearly two years and I've never been able to "Undo" an Escape + X  command ... aka a deleted cell.  And after some painful losses, I've learned to be very careful about deleting cells.  Most often I'll just Control + /  unwanted cells until I'm really sure I don't need those cells.  And even then, sometimes I regret deleting them.

Comment: Thanks @Gray! I feel you